# Surge Protection for Servers not Connected to UPS

Tags: electrical-power, surge-protection

For servers or network switches not protected by UPS, is there any product to guard against power surges / spikes?

Power conditioners available seem to be for home /audio video usage. Was looking at Tripplite ISOBLOk etc but they do not have solutions for 230V loads/ supply.

Is my only option to use a UPS for power regulation etc purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, yes. Check the product lists of the usual UPS culprits (APC for example). Plus you also can get something in your local computer shop. Even with insurance (if a power surge goes through).

Answer (score 0):

You can get power conditioners and such...but why take the risk? UPS units from APC (and some others) have insurance protection for your equipment and if you're talking about *servers*, the goal isn't protecting just from spikes, but to prevent data loss by allowing you time to do a proper shutdown if the need arises.

I've never heard people regret having too much protection on their data and equipment. I have heard the opposite, though. Get a UPS for your equipment.

Comment: Sorry for not elaborating. Space constraints in the rack results in me only having UPS connected to the first psu of each server. The redundant psu of each server is connected directly to the mains (seperate direct line). While this would only be used in the event of a failure of the first psu, I am worried that it gets damaged by some unforeseen event due to spikes or related power issues.

Comment: I personally would not configure my rack like that.  I think you run a higher risk of the secondary psu being blown out by the main versus your ups failing on the main.  If space were the limitation, I'd only connect the primary PSU.  Even if there's room for a power conditioner, I still wouldn't do it.  Virtually no gain, and some risk.

Comment: It would be a good idea...depending on budget and space...to get a second UPS anyway for the secondary power supply since there's a chance of a UPS dying out (battery, circuit issue, age of batteries, etc.) and killing the server during power interruption. But finding a way to get everything on some kind of UPS would probably still be better than one on a UPS and one on a line conditioner.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your feedback. I will try better next time to mitigate such risks. Really appreciate your time in answering this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have space in the rack for a 2nd UPS or line conditioner, then you can look into installing a surge suppressor (TVSS) at the breaker panel that feeds the rack.